# How AZ-CLI uses current context of user to perform CRUD operations on managed grafana resources

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, grafana, azure-managed-grafana

I wanted am currently building tool just like AZ-CLI to manage grafana resources (dashboards, datasources etc). Currently it uses API token for its authentication purpose but I wanted to add functionality just like AZ-CLI with which it can authenticate the user and then user can perform CRUD operation on grafana resources given that single user can be mapped to multiple instances. I would like to know the process flow.

I have checked jwt authentication since we have disable login form and just Active directory authentication is possible.